# Getting "not a dynamic executable" running "ldd mod_wsgi.o" on CentOS 5.5

Tags: mod-wsgi, python-2.7, ldd

I've installed Python 2.7.1 on 64-bit CentOS 5.5 and compiled mod_wsgi against 2.7.1. I'm building a DJango web application and need Python modules from 2.7 (CentOS built-in version of Python is only 2.4.3 and sorely lacking). I've basically followed the procedure on this great link:

http://willsani.com/2011/03/02/centos-5-5-x86_64-install-python-2-7/

So, I've now got a working version of Python 2.7.1 installed in /opt/python2.7.1. But, when I install my mod_wsgi.o module in Apache, Apache fails to start with:

```
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: 
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded
```

So, I ran the ldd command against my version of mod_wsgi.o and, instead of seeing the expected list of shared libraries, I see:

```
[root@ac5w15tps01 modules]# ldd mod_wsgi.o
    not a dynamic executable
```

Currently, my web application is running with mod_wsgi working fine against Python 2.4.3. Someone else set that up so not sure if they needed to do anything special - I inherited the setup. I've read everything related to building and installing mod_wsgi from http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/ and searched the web for answers. Can't see to find anything on this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) Did you actually run `ldd` on a different file (end in  `.o`) or is that a typo and you ment `mod_wsgi.so`? 2) What does `readelf` say about the file?  Perhaps you should just reinstall this module.

Comment: Problem solved. I ran only 'make' to build mod_wsgi.so but manually copied it into the Apache modules directory. I was trying to stepwise control upgrading so as to not break anything and figured I could do this (based on a comment in the wsgi wiki). Turns out that 'make install' uses Apache's apxs utility to convert the .so file to proper format. I decided to just go for it and ran "make install' and the resulting installed mod_wsgi.so file was properly showing shared libraries for Python 2.7.1 using ldd. :)